# Regex Match a string with a prefix, then case insensitive then with a postfix

Tags: regex, .net-core

So I need to match a string case-insensitively, that has a literal prefix and postfix.

for example Say I am looking for the following

- $Close(#$ScreenName: "System A Acknowledgement Popup")
- $Close(#$ScreenName: "System A Alarm Popup")
- $Close(#$ScreenName: "System A Menu")

the prefix `$Close(#$ScreenName: "` will always be the same and postfix `")` will always be the same. However, what is inside the quotes will not be, and I want to match it case-insensitively.

So if I tell it to look for "System A Acknowledgement Popup" it would match

```
$Close(#$ScreenName: "System A Acknowledgement Popup")
```

or

```
$Close(#$ScreenName: "system a acknowledgement popup")
```

Here is my code. I am trying to get a match count and then replace the match.

```
static string FixScreenCallsInFile(string FileContents, List<string> screenNamesToFindAndFix)
{

    foreach (var screenName in screenNamesToFindAndFix)
    {
        var ScreenNameHelper = (Old: $"$Close(#$ScreenName: \"{screenName}\")", New: $"$Close(\"{screenName}\")", OldSearchPattern: Regex.Escape($"$Close(#$ScreenName: \"{screenName}\")"));

        var CountMatch = Regex.Matches(FileContents, ScreenNameHelper.OldSearchPattern).Count;
        if (CountMatch > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{ScreenNameHelper.Old} count is {CountMatch} -> {ScreenNameHelper.New}");
            FileContents = Regex.Replace(FileContents, ScreenNameHelper.OldSearchPattern, ScreenNameHelper.New);
        }
    }

    return FileContents;
}
```

My hang-up is the case-insensitive screen name part.

Comment: You need to enable the case-insensitive `/i` modifier.

Comment: How do I do that on just the middle section inside the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the "game's rules" in any place of your string, you can use inline options `(?imnsx-imnsx)`. The `-` turns off the options.

Say, you need to match string `ABCabc`. Then pattern `ABC(?i)ABC` will match this string. In other words, first, it will strictly match `ABC`, but then all the permutations of cases of `ABC`: `abc`, `aBc`, `aBC` etc.

Comment: So, in other words, this is what I needed `\$Close\(\#\$ScreenName:\ "((?i)system a acknowledge popup)"\)`

Comment: @TheColonel26 Yes, exactly. This will force regex to do case-insensitive match. If you then need to cancel case-insensitive search, you just write `(?-i)`, as I said in the answer.

Comment: So instead of putting the Case In-sen part in a group, I could have done this `\$Close\(\#\$ScreenName:\ "(?i)system a acknowledge popup(?i-)"\)`?

Comment: Well, the cancelling `(?-i)` is not necessarily here, because after `popup` you don't search for words. You can eliminate it.